# i18n for JavaScript - The Best Practice?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

What's the current best practice of handling i18n in JavaScript?

I've heard some suggestions involving outputting all the i18n strings using PHP/Rails/etc. into a formatted JavaScript file of thousands of vars, but that simply sounds too rough a solution; moreover, there needs to be a way to detect which i18n strings are actually needed for the JS files that's gonna be loaded on a given page, but I got no idea how to implement this right now.

Some other suggestions I've heard involving setting up some kind of API between backend and frontend, using well-formatted JSON as the carrier of i18n strings, but that still doesn't solve the problem with redundant strings I might not need.

What's some of the best practices regarding i18n in JavaScript currently, that - if possible - also have a solution for detecting and sending only those strings that are actually needed on a given page?

Answer (score 2):

The 'best practice' really depends on how you build you application. Two examples:

- **Single page app.** Of course you'd want to just load all of the needed strings for you entire application in one go, as constantly fetching new strings would be a waste of time and resources.
- **Page with some JS-based content.** If you keep reloading the JS, you probably want to reduce the amount of strings as much as possible, and maybe even integrate the entire i18n dict in your HTML to avoid a AJAX call.

Either way, you'll want to reduce the amount of strings sent to the client to a bare minimum. While there are a lot of approaches, my favorite is to use pre-compiled templates (I like Mustache using Twitter's Hogan.js) with i18n extensions that don't only return a function to generate the HTML, but also a list of all translatable strings.

What you definitely **don't** want to do is to build a function that checks whether you already have a translation and if you don't then ask the server. This will make everything very slow and you don't want that. Either pre-load all translations, or don't translate those parts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "i18n". From your question it seems that you merely mean translatable strings extraction.
In this case, I lean to the single JS script generated from back-end. This may contain all the translatable strings in the array and some look-up method. I don't know if you call it "thousand variables approach", but that's what I am leaning to. I understand that you may dislike having things like `alert(tr.getString("some.key"))` in your code, but since you asked about the best practice...

I have seen many solutions, but most of them are just reinventing the wheel. The problem is, the wheel is rather squared in most cases...

Having said that, the i18n is way broader than simple string extraction. You have to take care about regional format support, correct collation, support for localizability (extracting strings is just one part) and more.
I can't really talk about "best practice", since the question is too broad. However, what I can say is, it really depends on the platform (i.e. programming language).